# PHP 5.2.x and 5.3.x

Tags: php

What are the differences between PHP 5.2.x and 5.3.x?

Because all extensions are made separately for these.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an [exhaustive list of backwards incompatible changes from 5.2 to 5.3 on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php).

PHP extensions depends on the `phpapi` version among other things, along with the Zend Module API version and the Zend Extension API version, which as far as I'm aware, changes at each PHP version because of the core changes made to the language. This explains why each PHP version has a new build for each extension.

Answer (score 6):

PHP 5.3 is a newer version with a number of [new features](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.new-features.php) (closures, namespaces, etc.). Is is the current stable version for the PHP project. PHP 5.2 is an older version, which is now heading towards the end of its support cycle - now only important security issues are being fixed. If you start a new project, start it with PHP 5.3.

When changes in PHP core are made that change the structure enough that extensions can no longer be compatible - the second digit in the version number is incremented (5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3). The first digit is for very major changes changing the whole language (like between PHP 4 and 5). Between 5.2 and 5.3, you can expect source code compatibility (though some [incompatibilities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) exist) but not binary module compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer in PHP official website.
In this page: [Migrating from PHP 5.2.x to PHP 5.3.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php).